# Chromecast CAF - Automatic Reconnection management

Tags: android, ios, google-cast

I'm developing both an iOS and Android sender app, and after migrating from Cast SDK v2 to the Cast Application Framework (CAF) I'm no longer able to handle myself the connection to an already running receiver app.

My desired UX here is to prevent auto reconnections when user kills the app and runs it again, the user must explicitly connect again. It seems to me that the Automatic Reconnection feature is kicking on no matter what. On [iOS](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/integrate#automatic_reconnection) nothing seems to be available, but on [Android](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/integrate#automatic_reconnection) even setting the proper values seems to have no effect at all.

Are we now forced to use this UX or there is a solution for this? I didn't find anything on the [UX guidelines](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ux_guidelines) forcing this behaviour.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a documentation about how to [Migrate CCL Sender App to the Cast Application Framework (CAF)](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/migrate_v2/ccl_sender).
All of the functionality of CCL has been implemented in CAF, so once you migrate, you will no longer need to use CCL.

> If you're building a CAF sender app or migrating to CAF, you should be
>   using CastContext and not GoogleAPIClient for accessing the Cast API.
>   It is proper to use GoogleAPIClient for accessing other Google Play
>   services APIs.

For more info about the **Reconnection Logic using CAF**, read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/migrate_v2/ccl_sender#reconnection_logic).